# It's possible clone a javascript div id with same function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to clone javascript div id with this code

```
<script>

    var div = document.getElementById('pruebaz2'),
                            clone = div.cloneNode(true); // true means clone  all childNodes and all event handlers
    clone.id = "pruebaz2";
    document.body.appendChild(clone);

</script>
```

but my clone div id not have any effect in my html page
my original id add a record when a doing a click

my clone id do nothing

how I can clone with same functionality

Comment: What functionality are you talking about? Could you give a bit more code?

Comment: You're trying to clone a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Shouldn't the clone have a different ID?

Comment: There is a perfect example to be found on W3school.. One of teh first things to pop up when seraching google for 'cloneNode' http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_clonenode

Comment: create a record when i click

Comment: Each id should be unique on the page. You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id. Maybe you should use a class?

Comment: Are you looking to clone not just the element, but the event handlers as well?

Comment: How do you handle a click? It looks like event delegation should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. Y**ou just didn't put any content into the cloned div so there was nothing to see.**

Also, don't give two elements the same id. That defeats the purpose of it.

Lastly, a "deep" clone does not duplicate event handlers. From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)**:

> Cloning a node copies all of its attributes and their values,
>   including intrinsic (in–line) listeners. It does not copy event
>   listeners added using addEventListener() or those assigned to element
>   properties. (e.g. node.onclick = fn) Moreover, for a  element,
>   the painted image is not copied.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('pruebaz2'),

clone = div.cloneNode(true); // true means clone  all childNodes and all event handlers
clone.id = "pruebaz3";
clone.innerHTML = "Cloned DIV";
document.body.appendChild(clone);
```

```html
<div id="pruebaz2">Original DIV</div>
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking to clone event handlers